# R: How to write a function to extract specific values from a dataframe in order to feed into another dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a dataframe that includes the lower and upper bound of a few parameters for each category of fruit. It looks sth like this:

```
+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Category | Parameter | Upper | Lower |
+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Apple    | alpha     | 10    | 20    |
+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Apple    | beta      | 20    | 30    |
+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Orange   | alpha     | 10    | 20    |
+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Orange   | beta      | 30    | 40    |
+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Orange   | gamma     | 50    | 60    |
+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Pear     | alpha     | 10    | 30    |
+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Pear     | beta      | 20    | 40    |
+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Pear     | gamma     | 20    | 30    |
+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Banana   | alpha     | 40    | 50    |
+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| Banana   | beta      | 20    | 40    |
+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

I would like to write a function that:

- Input is 1 fruit name `function("Apple")`
- Extracts the upper & lower values of all the parameters of this fruit
- Feed the upper and lower bound for alpha, beta, and gamma (if applicable) of selected fruit into the following process to make one dataframe:

```
param_grid_[fruit_name] <- expand.grid(alpha = seq(lower, upper, length.out = 100),
                                       beta  = seq(lower, upper, length.out = 100),
                                       gamma  = seq(lower, upper, length.out = 100))
```

- gamma is applicable only if the fruit has gamma parameter in the original table

For example, if my input to the function is "Apple", then I should end up having:

```
param_grid_Apple <- expand.grid(alpha = seq(10, 20, length.out = 100),
                                beta  = seq(20, 30, length.out = 100))
```

For example, if my input to the function is "Pear", then I should end up having:

```
param_grid_Pear <- expand.grid(alpha = seq(10, 30, length.out = 100),
                               beta  = seq(20, 40, length.out = 100),
                               gamma = seq(20, 30, length.out = 100))
```

I have tried  directly subsetting the row & col index. For example, for Apple's upper alpha, I would do df[2,3]. But this is a rather manual & unsophisticated way to do this. **I am wondering if I could wrap everything in a function to streamline this process.**

Still a beginner in R and trying to learn ways to streamline procedures by writing functions. Much appreciation for any help!

---

P.S. (FYI - maybe not be directly related to the center issue of this post) I am doing this so that I can feed **param_grid** into nls2 function to fit a curve for each fruit:

```
nls2(formula = ...,
     data = ...,
     start = param_grid, 
     algorithm = "brute-force",
     control = nls.control(maxiter = 1e4))
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach to consider with `purrr` package.

You can create a function and pass it your data frame, the fruit name, and the desired length for your sequence.

You can `filter` rows that correspond to your fruit, and then use `map2` to get sequences for each parameter. `cross_df` is comparable to `expand.grid` and will return a data frame.

```
library(purrr)

param_grid <- function(df, fruit, length) {
  df_fruit <- df %>%
    filter(Category == fruit) 
  
  map2(df_fruit$Upper, df_fruit$Lower, seq, length.out = length) %>%
    set_names(df_fruit$Parameter) %>%
    cross_df()
}

param_grid(df, "Apple", 100)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 1,000,000 x 3
   alpha  beta gamma
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  10      20    20
 2  10.2    20    20
 3  10.4    20    20
 4  10.6    20    20
 5  10.8    20    20
 6  11.0    20    20
 7  11.2    20    20
 8  11.4    20    20
 9  11.6    20    20
10  11.8    20    20
# … with 999,990 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! The bulk of the work is being done by `assign()` which can create named variables from string input for the names, `eval(parse())` which allows us to feed R commands in as character strings (even stored in variables!), and `do.call()` which can operate a function over a list of arguments, which allows us to programmatically build that list each time.

```
param_grid <- function(data, fruit_name) {
  require(dplyr)
  # Setting up the data 
  df <- data %>%
    filter(Category == fruit_name) %>%
    select(-Category)
  # assigning seqences for each parameter
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    assign(df$Parameter[i], seq(df$Lower[i], df$Upper[i], length.out = 100))
  }
  #putting them in a list for do.call
  list1 <-lapply(unique(df$Parameter), function(j) eval(parse(text = j)))
  # setting up the data frame for expand.grid
  df2 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, list1))
  names(df2) <- unique(df$Parameter)
  df_expand <- expand.grid(df2)
  return(df_expand)
}
```

It works!

```
param_grid_apple <- param_grid(fruit, "Apple")
head(param_grid_apple, 10)
      alpha beta
1  20.00000   30
2  19.89899   30
3  19.79798   30
4  19.69697   30
5  19.59596   30
6  19.49495   30
7  19.39394   30
8  19.29293   30
9  19.19192   30
10 19.09091   30
dim(param_grid_apple)
[1]  10000      2

param_grid_pear <- param_grid(fruit, "Pear")
head(param_grid_pear, 10)
      alpha beta gamma
1  30.00000   40    30
2  29.79798   40    30
3  29.59596   40    30
4  29.39394   40    30
5  29.19192   40    30
6  28.98990   40    30
7  28.78788   40    30
8  28.58586   40    30
9  28.38384   40    30
10 28.18182   40    30

dim(param_grid_pear)
[1]  10000      3
```